# Intellisense with a DLL in the GAC

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, intellisense, gac

Hopefully you can help me with this. An assembly is already in the GAC. To enable intellisense on this on page controls, is there anyway of having a centralised DLL to achieve intellisense without the DLL in the /Bin/?

I tried adding the DLL to PublicAssemblies but when I "Add Reference" it says it already exists in the project. (GAC reference)

Help?

**EDIT:** Intellisense with page controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out: In  I had imported the assembly but required Version, Culture, PublicKeyToken for it to work from the GAC.

INCORRECT:

```
<add tagPrefix="myCMS" namespace="myCMS.UI.Controls" assembly="myCMS"/>
```

WORKING:

```
<add tagPrefix="myCMS" namespace="myCMS.UI.Controls" assembly="MyCMS,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99a59984a224c014"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether the assembly is in the GAC or the Bin, you should still have intellisense as the assembly will be loaded into the visual studio process.  If you don't get intellisense it is likely that there was an exception thrown while compiling in the background to provide intellisense.  One common reason that I have seen is that a dependent assembly fails to load.

You can debug this by attaching a debugger to Visual Studio.  I would take the following steps to do this:

1. Open two instances of visual studio (run as administrator)
2. Attach one to the other (Tools -> Attach to Process)
3. Open your project in the instance being debugged.

Note that to actually catch the exception you will need to change a few debugging options.  First you would need to make sure that the Just My Code checkbox is unchecked in the General debugging options in Visual Studio.  The second is on the exceptions dialog you will need to catch thrown exceptions.  The exception dialog is under the Debug menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi alhalama, correct - intellisense does work on the DLL, I was very unclear to start with sorry, since corrected. The assembly has page controls and the Controls and Attributes aren't 'found'?

Comment: I worked it out: In <system.web><pages><controls> I had imported the assembly but required Version, Culture, PublicKeyToken for it to work.